# Convert column's data to a row

Tags: excel, vba, csv, text

I have a Kaspersky security console report generated in .csv or text format:

> Name IP Domaine Server 192.168.1.100 home.local Machine 192.168.1.10 home.local PC 192.168.1.15 home.local

It is in one line and separated by tabs. I want it converted/displayed to be like this:

```
Name        IP             Domaine
Server      192.168.1.100  home.local         
Machine     192.168.1.10   home.local
PC          192.168.1.15   home.local
```

Comment: Does each line have three entries?  Or can the number of entries vary?

Answer (score 2):

Without a formula or VBA, you can use Text to Columns.

Have your cell selected and go to Data tab --> Text to Columns.  Choose "Delimited" and click "Next".  Then, choose "Space", and click "Finish".

This will separate the data when there's a space.  You can then just cut/paste the three columns at a time.

[image]

If you can use macros, the following should do what you want (I tested it with four rows):

```
Sub delimit()
Dim i&, iRow&, k&, x&, tempI&, lastRow&
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

rng.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False

' Now we have our rows, let's see how many times we have to copy down. We're going to divide by 3
Dim iCol&, numNewRows&
tempI = 1
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To 600000
    If i + 3 > lastRow Then Exit For
    i = tempI
    iCol = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    numNewRows = (iCol - 3) / 3

    ' Let's insert those new rows and start cutting down!
    Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + numNewRows, 1)).EntireRow.Insert
    tempI = Cells(i + 1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    For x = 1 To numNewRows
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, numNewRows)).Offset(0, 3 * x).Cut Destination:= _
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, numNewRows)).Offset(x, 0)

    Next x

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: yes this is how i do it .. for a fewer number of lines .. but sometimes it has more than 900 machine name .. i cant do all of them like that

Comment: @MohamedMaElainine - ah okay, I'll get a macro for ya.

Comment: @MohamedMaElainine - I have updated my answer with a macro, this should work for you.  I am not sure if you're always going to have 3 new rows to copy, so I tried to make it dynamic in case there's more.  However, if they don't come in "groups of 3", then it might give some errors...so let me know.

Comment: i'm having troube running it .. i should test on kespersky center data report next monday .. thank you a lot

Comment: "... I'm having trouble running it." - how so? Are you getting errors? Not sure how to implement VBA? Let meet know and I'll see what's up.

Answer (score 0):

i used this macro instead :

```
    Sub ETL()
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    Dim CountCols As Integer
    nombre = InputBox(Prompt:="Entrer nombre colonnes:")
   If nombre = "" Then Exit Sub
   CountCols = nombre

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Output"

     LastCol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(1, Sheets("Feuil1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     Dim copyRange  As Range
     Dim countD As Integer
     countD = 1
     '.Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, 4)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    For j = 1 To LastCol Step CountCols

        Set copyRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(1, j), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(1, j + CountCols - 1))
        copyRange.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Cells(countD, 1)
        countD = countD + 1
    Next j



End Sub
```

thanks everyone

Comment: ...this works for you?? It doesn't break the info. up like you asked...unless I'm missing something? How does this work for the question you asked?  What does this do that mine doesn't (or vice versa)? (Just so I can learn in the future how to better answer SO questions)